# How to serialize derived class to base class?

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to serialize object and pass it to method which parameter type is parent of object.

For example, I have this classes.

```
public class Base
{
    public string TypeName => GetType().Name;
    public string Data => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int data1 { get; set; }
    public int data2 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    ...
}

....
```

I wrote the code as follows,

```
var obj = new Derived { Name = "John", data1 = 2000, data2 = 1500 };
Send(obj);
```

And Send(..) method is,

```
public void Send(Base info)
{
    // Do Something with "info".
}
```

When I instantiate variable obj, program has fallen into infinite recursion because of "Data" in Base class.

How can I change the code?

Answer (score 1):

Infinite recursion is caused by the *Data* property, which is serialized - that causes serialization of the *this* and the loop begins.

The best solution would be to simply change the property into method, which would not be serialized and would better serve the purpose. If you are dead set on property - you could just try marking the property with http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm which will cause it to be ignored during serialization.